# ASP classic CLng function - convert to PHP

Tags: php, asp-classic

I have an old site created with ASP classic and now I got up the courage to convert it to PHP. Must say I am NOT an expert in neither of this languages.

There is a simple function that is driving me crazy. It uses CLng in a way I never seen before and I can't find a similar method in PHP.

Here is the function in ASP classic:

```
Function TransferDecode(ByRef Source)
Dim C, I, P, S, K
    C = Len(Source) / 2
    TransferDecode = ""
    For I = 0 to C - 1
        P = I * 2 + 1
        S = Mid(Source, P, 2)
        K = CLng("&H" & S)
        TransferDecode = TransferDecode & Chr(K)
    Next
End Function
```

And here is my (uncessefull) attempt to convert to PHP:

```
function transferDecode($source) {
    $r = '';
    $c = strlen($source) / 2;
    for ($i = 0; $i <= $c - 1; $i++) {
        $p = $i * 2 + 1;
        $s = substr($source, $p, 2);
        $k = '&H'.$s;
        $r .= chr((int)$k);
    }
    return $r;
}
```

Please, can someone explain me what "CLng("&H" & S)" do? Is there a similar CLng method in PHP?

Thank you!

Comment: `TransferDecode` simply does what PHP's [hex2bin](http://php.net/manual/en/function.hex2bin.php) does. You can simply use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd try something like that:

```
$r .= chr(intval($s, 16));
```

note: variable `$k` is not used at all

also, strings in vbscript are 1-based, while in php are 0-based, so `$p` should be calculated as `$p = $i * 2;`